# Grails 2.4.4 jdk8u60 SEVERE: Problems copying method. Incompatible JVM?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, java-8, grails-2.4

I created a project grails 2.4.4 in Intellij Idea 15 (jdk1.8u60) when I try to run my project I get this long endless log generated:

```
    Jan 27, 2016 1:09:41 PM org.springsource.loaded.jvm.JVM copyMethod
SEVERE: Problems copying method. Incompatible JVM?
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springsource.loaded.jvm.JVM.copyMethod(JVM.java:134)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.OriginalClassInvoker.createJavaMethod(OriginalClassInvoker.java:68)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredMethods(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:360)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:261)
    at org.c ...
```

how can I run my project ?

Answer (score 1):

I know 2.4.4 doesn't work with 1.8_60. Change the jdk to 1.7. I think 1.8_30 is compatible but I'm not sure. I use 1.7 and works fine.